# Ruby hash.update / map values only contained within brackets

Tags: ruby, regex, dictionary, split

I have the following array of hashes:

```
[
  {"type"=>"paragaph", "class"=>"red", "content"=>"[class:intro|body:This is the introduction paragraph.][body:This is the second paragraph.]"}, 
  {"type"=>"image", "class"=>"grid", "content"=>"[id:1|title:image1][id:2|title:image2][id:3|title:image3]"}
]
```

I'm trying to convert the hash values containing square brackets into an array of values. This perfectly well - the problem being it destroys all other hash values that do not contain square brackets.

```
pipe_regex = /\|\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/
colon_regex = /\:\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/

array_hash.map {|m| m.update(m) {|k,v| v.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).map {|m| m[0].split(pipe_regex)}.map {|m| m.map {|n| n.split(colon_regex)}}}}
```

It's a bit messy but the code above finds each hash value and divides them based on the '[]' characters - but also seems to destroy anything without '[]'. It then proceeds to split them at '|' then splits ':' which appears to work perfectly fine.

I then convert the values into a hash so the original containing square brackets is now an array of hashes.

```
array_hash.map {|m| m.update(m) {|k,v| v.map {|n| Hash[n]}}}
```

This also seems to work fine. The final result of everything collates to:

```
[
  {"type"=>[], "class"=>[], "content"=>[{"class"=>"intro", "body"=>"This is the introduction paragraph."}, {"body"=>"This is the second paragraph."}]}, 
  {"type"=>[], "class"=>[], "content"=>[{"id"=>"1", "title"=>"image1"}, {"id"=>"2", "title"=>"image2"}, {"id"=>"3", "title"=>"image3"}]}
]
```

---

How can I make `.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/)` only apply to strings containing '[]'? So this is the result:

```
[
  {"type"=>"paragraph", "class"=>"red", "content"=>[{"class"=>"intro", "body"=>"This is the introduction paragraph."}, {"body"=>"This is the second paragraph."}]}, 
  {"type"=>"image", "class"=>"grid", "content"=>[{"id"=>"1", "title"=>"image1"}, {"id"=>"2", "title"=>"image2"}, {"id"=>"3", "title"=>"image3"}]}
]
```

Comment: What about applying what you've described ? Like inserting ternary operator before .scan method ? Such as ```{|k,v| v[/\[.*\]/] ? v.scan(\[(.*?)\]) ... : v} ...``` ?

Comment: Awesome, works a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working algorithms:

```
array_hash.map {|m| m.update(m) {|k,v| v[/\[.*\]/] ? v.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).map {|m| m[0].split(pipe_regex)}.map {|m| m.map {|n| n.split(colon_regex)}} : v}}
array_hash.map {|m| m.update(m) {|k,v| v.kind_of?(Array) ? v.map {|n| Hash[n]} : v}}
```